# Text Styling in Android

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I want to show user text-data opened in edittext where text is stylish. Like, some words are bold , some are italiac , lines are colored differently based on user preferences etc.. How can I show such stylish data to user ; is it possible using edittext ?

Also, is there a way I can embed CSS like quality in my app without its interaction with web. I just want to create a beautiful and colorful app. Please provide any tips. I'm too new to android.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to [style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) the text inside the editText?

Comment: yes, but not all the text with same color or font. For ex.: some lines are red colored , some are blue , some words have large font etc.... I mean if it is possible for each set of words to have its own styling properties.

Comment: Then checkout Raghunandan's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Spannable String.

```
   EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);  
  String s= "Hello Everyone";
  SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
  ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,5, 0);
  ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0); 
  ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 5, 0); 
  ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
  ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
  et.append(ss1);
```

[image]

For more styling check the link @ http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177

Comment: @shadow this does not use css. But this works for styling text in textview or editext

Comment: is there also a possibility of using css like structures being used for styling in android. If there is , can you please link me up.

Comment: @shadow i am not aware of that. so i cannot comment on that. But i have used html not aware of css

Comment: @shadow does the above not help yoiu?

Comment: it does. I upvoted it. Will wait for sometime before marking it as answer.

Comment: @shadow fair enough if some gives a better answer you can accept the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTF files and store in your assets folder .

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Tangerine_Regular.ttf");
 nametodisplay.setTypeface(font);
```

nametodisplay is a text view .
 Try similar for edittext.I never tried it myself though.

Comment: I think you r just loading TTF font-file here to change typeface.

Comment: I am just using ttf files to get some extra typeface other than normal bold and italic . Otherwise The answer above is suited most